# What's is MySQL equivalent of SQL server table schema

Tags: mysql, sql-server, schema

I have spent most of my development time on building .NET application on SQL server. Now I am doing them on MySQL server. How can I partition MySQL tables into namespaces. In SQL server I used table schema but apparently in MySQL there is no such concept called table schema.

What's the naming conversion for MySQL table namespaces. (E.g. is it Products.Finance, Products.HR or Products_Finance, Products_HR or you ignore such naming altogether?)

Comment: In MySql its named databases. This is also called schema in some documentation. So you can access or create it like : SEKECT * FROM  SCHEMANAME.TABLENAME ... . Without schema name MySQL will use the selected schema with USE SCHEMANAME;

Comment: See this pls: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-database/

Comment: 'What's the naming conveNTion?' - There isn't one it's entirely up to you.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/glossary.html#glos_schema) , a schema is the synonym of a database. You can use the keyword SCHEMA instead of DATABASE in MySQL SQL syntax.

**Example :** to create a schema that has an student details table. Give authority on the table to user DAVID. :

```
CREATE SCHEMA INVENTRY

CREATE TABLE PART (IDNO  SMALLINT NOT NULL,
                        SNAME    VARCHAR(40),
                        CLASS INTEGER)

GRANT ALL ON PART TO DAVID
SELECT * FROM INVENTRY.PART
```